# Is it possible to change date format in date time picker?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I found a great date time picker based on jQuery-ui http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/, but suddenly realized that i can't modify date format... Tried something like this:

```
jQuery('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
        timeFormat: 'HH:mm'
    }).formatDate('yy-mm-dd');
```

Can someone show an example on it?

Comment: How would you like it formatted?

Comment: @TimBJames 2013-01-17 09:38

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the code:

```
jQuery('.datetimepicker')
    .datetimepicker({ 
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', 
        timeFormat: 'HH:mm' 
     });
```

Comment: oh, found a little bug... if in input value date is in other format it throws an error.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

This will set the date format to `"yy-mm-dd"`

```
 $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat = "yy-mm-dd";
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible, have a look at the `dateFormat` option in the [API Documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat) for the datepicker

This will work,

```
jQuery('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
        timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

yes it is possible to format the date. Refer the [link](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate)  given in this API

```
$.datepicker.formatTime(format, timeObj, options)
```

Refer the Formatting tab in this [url](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/). At the bottom of page u find the option to format a date

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

jQuery('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    dateFormat: "D MM d, yy"
});

and see this for more documentation : http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/#tp-formatting

Answer (score 0):

POSSIBLE, heres an example link.
extracting from this example souldnt be a problem i guess :)

http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/date-formats.html

Answer (score 0):

Just to add that none of the above worked for me, but the following did:

```
$(".datetimepicker").DateTimePicker({
    dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
});
```

Regards

Liam