# jQuery UI Datepicker not showing previously chosen date/time

Tags: cakephp, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker, cakephp-1.2

I am using jQuery UI Datepicker (http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/). Everything is working correctly except for one thing. I can choose the date/time I want and save. Everything is stored in the database correctly and when I come back to the editor, I see the date/time that I had previously saved. Everything good so far. The problem is when I try to edit the date/time. See what happens:

[image]

Notice how even though the input field textbox has the date/time "2017-11-01 08:23:00", the calendar is by default showing the current day of my computer, September 20th, and for time it is showing the default value of 12:00 am. Why isn't the calendar respecting the values that appear in the input field textbox?

EDIT: This is what I am using in my JavaScript file:

```
// jQuery UI Datepicker (http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/)
$('#start_date').datetimepicker({
    timeInput: true,
    timeFormat: "hh:mm tt"
});
```

This is what I have in my PHP/.ctp file (I am using CakePHP 1.2):

```
<div>
    <?php echo $form->input('start_date', array('id' => 'start_date', 'label' => __l('Start Date'), 'type' => 'text'));?>
</div>
```

Comment: I suspect the problem may be that in the database, the entry appears as "2017-11-01 08:23:00", and jQuery UI Datepicker might be expecting this format: "11/01/2017 08:23 am".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The accepted answer at [Is it possible to change date format in date time picker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14475534/is-it-possible-to-change-date-format-in-date-time-picker) gave me the hint to find the solution for what I needed. This was the solution for me:

```
$('#start_date').datetimepicker({
    timeInput: true,
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', 
    timeFormat: 'HH:mm:ss'
});
```

I simply had to follow the same format of how the database stores the date and time, since that is how CakePHP retrieves the data. Now everything works correctly for me.