# Find all datetimepicker controls in a page

Tags: jquery, datepicker, datetimepicker, timepicker

I am using several `datetimepicker` control in a page. All of the are serves different functionalities. So i have created individual class for each of them. I have to change the datetime format dynamically for all those controls. also, i need to change the datetime string which is already populated by my back end code. backend code is updating textbox with mm/dd/yyyy format but i need to change it dynamically.How can i achieve these ?

I saw after rendering all controls has `"hasdatepicker"` class. But i am unable to access the control.

```
$('.hasdatepicker').datetimepicker({ dateFormat: localStorage.serverDateTimeFormat }).val();
```

Should be able to change the pre populated text with new date time format and all `datetimepicker` should be able to change the datepicker format.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the value and format like this:

```
$('.yourDateTimePickerIdentifier').datetimepicker({value:'14.04.2018',  format:'d.m.Y'});
```

Ensure you have a indentifier for all of the datetimepickers. Use a class rather than an ID

Comment: Yeah but the problem is that i have 24 different datetimepicker with 24 different classes (some crazy UI complexity so that, i cant use less than those many controls). so if i specify all 24 then its fine. But i have to change all datatime format at one shot.

Comment: What format are the classes in? If they use a consistent naming convention then you could possibly use wildcards in the identifying part. If sounds like you're using classes in the way that you should be using id's. Can you give me some example of the classes used please?

Comment: hey ducker .. thanks for showing up. i found the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/14475579/2404066 . This is changing default date format for all datetime picker.